# Summation of alternating series, Mercator series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, closed-form

I am struggling with solving sum of this alternate series:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}\ 
$$

I know that:

$$
\log(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cdot x^n\
$$

But It seems that I can't find a way to get to this form.
Thanks.

Comment: your sum has the value $$-1+2\ln(2)$$

Comment: Yes I know that, Wolframalpha gives me the same result but I don't know how to get there. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Due to properties of power series, one is allowed to write
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\int_{0}^1t^{n}dt
\\\\&=\int_{0}^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}t^{n}}{n}\:dt
\\\\&=\int_0^1\ln(1+t)dt
\end{align}
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: Yes I got the result 2ln(2)-1. Thank you very much for your help. So 1/(n+1) got replaced by inegral(t^n dt)? Can you tell me how to define boundaries of integral?

Comment: @AdnanSelimovic You are welcome. We have, for $n\ge0$, $$\int_0^1 t^n dt=\left[\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^1=\frac{1^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{0^{n+1}}{n+1} =\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 5):

It is well-known fact that

> $${ \sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { (-1)^{ n+1 } }{ n }  } =\ln { 2 } . }$$

So 
$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  } \frac { (-1)^{ n+1 } }{ n(n+1) } =\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  } \left( \frac { (-1)^{ n+1 } }{ n } -\frac { (-1)^{ n+1 } }{ n+1 }  \right) =\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  } \frac { (-1)^{ n+1 } }{ n } -\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  } \frac { (-1)^{ n+1 } }{ n+1 } =\left( 1-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 3 } -\frac { 1 }{ 4 } +.. \right) -\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 3 } +\frac { 1 }{ 4 } +.. \right) =\\ =\ln { 2 } -\left( -\ln { 2 } +1 \right) =2\ln { 2 } -1\\ $$